# Extra forwardslashes when converting JSON to string

Tags: qt, qt5

When I try to convert JSON into a string, i get extra forwardslashes in the outputted string. I've tried changing the formatting but nothing works. Will I have to manually do a string replace to fix this?

```
QVariantMap tx;
tx["type"] = "beacon";
QVariantMap tx_data;
tx_data["serverVersion"] = VERSION;
tx_data["clientVersion"] = 1;
tx_data["port"] = server->serverPort();
tx["data"] = QVariant(tx_data);
QByteArray data = QJsonDocument(QJsonObject::fromVariantMap(tx)).toJson(QJsonDocument::Compact);

qDebug() << "Server: Broadcast:" << data;
```

Output:

```
"{\"data\":{\"clientVersion\":1,\"port\":0,\"serverVersion\":1},\"type\":\"beacon\"}"
```

Comment: The output of qDebug() is only intended for debugging purposes. Check what's actually in the string with your debugger.

Comment: thank you, seems it works correctly.